# Having issues with php operator

Tags: php, operator-keyword

I want to compare two values and if one is greater than the other then it performs some update in the database, however the result always returns false. this is an example of the part of the code im struggling with:

```
<?php 
$page = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `site` WHERE `id`='{$posts['him']}'"));
$count = file_get_contents($site->site_url . 'count/numbercheck.php?url=' . ($page->url));
if(is_numeric($count) && $count > $posts['count'])
{
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';   
}

?>
```

this echos false. The $posts['count'] comes from a jquery post on another page. and I'm sure that $count is greater than $posts['count']. And just to be sure then I did this:

```
<?php 
$page = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `site` WHERE `id`='{$posts['him']}'"));
$count = file_get_contents($site->site_url . '/count/numbercheck.php?url=' . ($page->url));
if(is_numeric($count) && $count > $posts['count'])
{
    echo 'true' . $count . ' ' . $posts['count'];
}else{
    echo 'false' . $count . ' ' . $posts['count'];  
}

?>
```

that returns "false 86 85". I don't get it, what I am doing wrong? its clear to me that 86 is greater than 85.

Comment: Have you checked to see which part of your AND is failing? Is the `is_numeric` returning false, or is it definitely the comparison part? Have you tried running `is_numeric` on `$posts['count']`?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: var_dump() the $count and $posts['count'] values to test what datatype they are and what they actually contain

Answer (score 3):

`file_get_contents()` returns a string value so it is always going to evaluate as `false` when using `is_numeric()`

If you want to return an array (one item for each line in the file), you should use `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Even if the contents of the string are of a numeric type?

Comment: @Matt According to the docs, it either returns a string of the file contents or false on failure.

Comment: is_numeric() returns TRUE for a string like '42'. is_int() however, doesn't. - see example at http://php.net/is_numeric

Comment: For completeness sake, the numeric comparision works because "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically"

Comment: Yes without knowing the value of what is in the returned file there would be cases where is_numeric could return a true there I suppose.  Though, to me, this would be very poor coding practice rather than cast the returned value to an integer specifically and then do the comparison. It would make is much more understandable to the reader of the code as to what the intention is.

Comment: Thank you for the help I've identified the problem. the `$count` returns false if I run `is_numeric()` check on it. I convert it to int with `intval()`. I will look into the article you recommended. I'm fairly new to php coding.